System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Class not registered error for COM component with CLSID {4781DA29-BD5C-11D1-94B1-0000B43369D3}
I'm working on a project targeting .NET Framework 4.8 and encountering an issue related to a COM component used for encryption and decryption. The specific error message is:


System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x80040154
  Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4781DA29-BD5C-11D1-94B1-0000B43369D3} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at BusinessLayer.Login..ctor() in C:\Users\user\source\repos\India1-OTC-Backend-WebPortal-Service\BusinessLayer\Login.cs:line 12
   at UI.Check..ctor() in C:\Users\user\source\repos\India1-OTC-Backend-WebPortal-Service\UI\Check.aspx.cs:line 13
   at ASP.check_aspx..ctor()
   at __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_52iecicc.Create_ASP_check_aspx()



Background

Error Description: The 80040154 Class not registered error suggests
that the COM component with CLSID
{4781DA29-BD5C-11D1-94B1-0000B43369D3} is not registered on the
system. This component is supposed to handle encryption and
decryption tasks.
COM Component: The component in question is RC4Lib.RC4. I have been
unable to locate any library or documentation for this COM component.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken
I searched the Windows Registry (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID) for the CLSID but did not find any relevant entries.
Component Library:
I have been unable to find the RC4Lib.RC4 library or any installer for it.
Application Pool Settings:
I confirmed that the application pool in IIS is configured for .NET Framework 4.8, but I am unsure if the application needs to run in 32-bit mode.
Questions

Does the absence of the RC4Lib.RC4 library or installer indicate that I need to run my application in 32-bit mode?
How can I obtain or register the missing COM component when the DLL file and installer are not available?
Are there alternative steps I should take to resolve this Class not registered error, especially considering the .NET Framework 4.8
environment?
Is it possible that this issue is related to a mismatch in architecture (32-bit vs. 64-bit) between the COM component and the application?
Given that the component is used for encryption and decryption, are there modern alternatives or best practices for handling these tasks in a .NET Framework 4.8 environment?

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!


Maybe 2. Ask whoever wrote this component, it's not a Windows-provided component. 3. Not really if the component is missing. 4. Yes, if you have a dll and it doesn't work. No if you don't have any binary. 5. For RC4 you don't even need a component, google for it, or use WinRT's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetricalgorithmnames


BTW, RC4 is no longer considered a security algorithm, so your first task should be switching to another more secure algorithm, instead of trying to get RC4 working.
